# Use of IFS in “for loop”

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
lis="a:b:c:d:"

IFS=:
```

If I run the following code,

```
for i in "a:b:c:d:";
do 
    echo the output is $i
done
```

I get:

```
the output is a b c d
```

If I replace "a:b:c:d:" with $lis instead:

```
for i in $lis;
do 
    echo the output is $i
done
```

I have the expected output:

```
the output is a
the output is b
the output is c
the output is d
```

I wonder what is wrong, $lis is basically the same as "a:b:c:d"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Comment: '$lis is basically the same as "a:b:c:d"' ... `"$lis"` might be, but `$lis` isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The big difference is where word splitting is performed. Double quotes ensure that a literal string or quoted variable like `"$lis"` would be treated as single item

```
for i in "a:b:c:d:";
do 
    echo the output is $i
done
```

Therefore in this loop the double quoted `"a:b:c:d:"` is a single item, hence why you see only one line of output

```
the output is a b c d
```

---

```
for i in $lis;
do 
    echo the output is $i
done
```

Here the `$lis` is unquoted, hence the shell will perform word splitting according to the `IFS` value you've set. The shell will see there's 4 items provided to the for loop. Hence why you see four lines of output.

If you double quote `"$lis"` variable, the word splitting won't be performed, hence you should see identical output - only one line - to the first case.

Comment: How can you set `IFS` only within the scope of the `for` block?